# Assigning an IP address to a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I want to access my docker container using a static local IP address.

Here is the compose file I have:

```
version: '3' # I changed this to 2 as well.
services:
  server:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      my-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.17

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

I expected that going on `172.20.0.17` would reach me to the nginx site. Instead I just get `172.20.0.17 took too long to respond.` error.

Note that when I use traditional port forwarding everything works fine:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "4560:80"
```

and go on localhost:4560, the welcome page loads as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

I am running docker using Docker Desktop (Mac).

Comment: You can't directly access the Docker-internal IP addresses at all using Docker Desktop (and it's not a good practice on native Linux either).  Delete all of the `networks:` configuration in the first setup and use the working `ports:`.